# Launch external editor in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

On my local machine, I have textmate installed, and in the terminal, I can do things like `mate index.html`, and this will launch textmate.

However now I'm using Vagrant and VBox. On a virtual machine, I can't use `mate` anymore. Is it possible to use an external editor like textmate on virtual machine files?

Answer (score 1):

1.1+ Shared folder has been renamed to Synced Folder. By default the directory where `Vagrantfile` resides will be mounted as `/vagrant` via `vboxsf`. You can add more and change the default behaviour.

Please refer to the v2 docs => http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html

> BTW: If your host is Linux, using `sshfs` is good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to mount a share and edit from your host... This is easily done with vagrant share :) You may want your files to live on the host permanently or on the guest depending of your situation.

You can check the documentation for this : http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html